# How do I change the background color of a button programmatically in Xcode 10?

Tags: xcode10

I'm running Xcode 10 and swift 4 and I'm trying to change the background color of my button through code. Here's what I've tried and the resulting error.

[image]

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

what ever you are using backgroundColor property on is not a UIButton, it's a function who get's UIButton and return Void, so find your mistake and call backgroundColor on UIButton object.

Answer (score 0):

It should work but still try it this way:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var selectAllBtn: UIButton!

    self.selectAllBtn.backgroundColor = .blue
```

p.s
see if the button is set as here